# Can I install/uninstall programs on a windows drive using a Ubuntu 14.04 bootable flash drive?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

Questions says most of it. I'm just wondering if I can add or remove programs on a windows hard drive using a Ubuntu 14.04 bootable flash drive. Mostly to get past windows admin privileges.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand your goal here you want to bypass some the administrator permissions.

**Solution 1 :**

You can easily install chntpw

```
sudo apt-get install chntpw
```

and simply reset the administrator password to have full system access.

**Solution 2**

You can emulate a windows executable on Linux using wine and playonlinux or make the installation on a windows virtual machine using virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get install wine playonlinux
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

then you can move the installed files to the windows partition in the respective system location and use chntpw to make the required regedit modifications.

PS :

concerning the first solution, I am aware that there is a possibility to login into the administrator account without resetting the password but I do not remember the trick. I think it is done somehow with Linux but I am not sure it might be a bootable windows cd.